# Manually trigger Windows Error Reporting from a Outlook COM Add-In

Tags: outlook-addin, windows-error-reporting, winqual, comaddin

I am writing a Outlook COM Add In using Visual Studio 2008 and VSTO.  If an exception goes unhandled in the add in, I would like it to trigger Windows Error Reporting (WER).  Our company has access to WinQual so that we can get reports of WER reports from users that occur in our program. Is there some way to do this?

From what I can tell, this isn't possible, but wanted to check to see if there was a way. WER is only triggered when an application generates an unhandled exception.  An Outlook Add In run in Outlook and Outlook has exception handlers around the calls to COM Add In to protect against a COM Add In causing Outlook to crash. Since Outlook doesn't crash, WER doesn't get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the same question (possibly by you!) found on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c1f418f-12de-422a-98eb-773783ed3ffa/can-a-vsto-outlook-add-in-trigger-windows-error-reporting-wer):

> As you said, WER is activated by a crash or hang and exceptions do not trigger that unless they lead to those conditions. Well, just imagine that unhandled exceptions (which even could be thrown in user code) triggered WER, Microsoft would get millions of reports. If you find a problem with VSTO, feel free to report it through Microsoft Connect ro share it with us on forum.

It doesn't quite get there, but the subtext would appear to be that it'll never happen.